# Dealing with dynamic Amazon server

Tags: amazon-ec2, dynamic-ip

I have a VM on Amazon.  Each day when I start it, it gives me a new IP like

```
ec2-123-45-67-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

It's a Windows-based machine. I want to install some software on that VM so that I don't need to remember that dynamic IP again and again for accessing via remote-desktop software and browsing URLs.

Is there any free server dealing with that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dynamic DNS provider so you have an easy to remember (and fixed) URL for your machine. You will need to set up an account with a Dynamic DNS provider and install their update client on your VM. Set the client to run when the VM starts, so its new IP will be updated with the DNS server.

A few free Dynamic DNS options:

- http://dyn.com/
- http://www.no-ip.com/personal/

Comment: Misseed the comment from ceejayoz

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately your PublicDNS/IP will always get changed at start/stop, but there is a workaround which implies using EIP(Elastic IP). You can create yourself an EIP and assign it to this server. In case of a stop/start you'll need to do the assign of the EIP again though since in case of a server stop the EIP gets de-assigned. Also please note there is a fee of $0.005 per Elastic IP address not associated with a running instance per hour on a pro rata basis as per http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Answer (score 1):

Just put the machine inside a VPC (doesn't cost extra) and you can control all EIP associations.